# Did Mike Webster pull out and glue in his own teeth?

Tags: united-states, football

In the 2015 American biographical sports drama film [Concussion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Concussion_(2015_film)), it is claimed that [Mike Webster](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mike_Webster)

> pulled his own teeth out and superglued them back in.

Is this claim true?

Comment: Who is Iron Mike?

Comment: @iamnotmaynard Pittsburgh Steeler Mike Webster

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to [League of Denial: The NFL's concussion crisis](https://books.google.com/books?id=uFAxBgAAQBAJ&pg=PA326&dq=%22he%20was%20supergluing%20his%20teeth%20back%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwi2meqawqLMAhUBUz4KHW2mD4YQ6AEIHTAA#v=onepage&q=%22he%20was%20supergluing%20his%20teeth%20back%22&f=false):

> Pam Webster: His teeth were falling out. His body—he had cellulitis. He had a heart—his heart, you know, was getting enlarged.
>
> Colin Webster, son: You know, he was supergluing his teeth back into his head, and he actually made that work.

So, according to his wife and son, yes he was gluing teeth, but he wasn't pulling out good teeth, rotten teeth were falling out.

Comment: Sounds like he wasn't actually *pulling them out himself* but rather they were just falling out?

Comment: @AdrianLarson he wasn't pulling out good teeth, these were rotten teeth that fell out or were about to fall out, I don't know exactly

Comment: @AdrianLarson I think they just fell out. Another quote is "his teeth began to fall out.  He couldn't afford a dentist, and so 'he'd Super Glue his teeth back into his head,' said Colin" https://books.google.com/books?id=4VITAAAAQBAJ&pg=PT102&dq=mike+webster+superglue+teeth&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiWv_fNxqLMAhWFHh4KHX2ECxcQ6AEITTAF#v=onepage&q=mike%20webster%20superglue%20teeth&f=false Colin also said this was about 10 teeth that were lost and then superglued, which was "kind of awesome in a not necessarily so awesome way".